# Where is "woocommerce_after_shop_loop" function defined?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use a Woocommerce and premium theme. I have some problems with translate. I translate some of words English to Turkish on source code. I have a message under my product page. **"No More Available Items"**. woocommerce_after_shop_loop function bring this message to page. I dont know how can i edit this message now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_after_shop_loop` hook runs the `wc_no_products_found` function in this file:

```
../woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php
```

Then the `wc_no_products_found` function loads the `loop/no-products-found.php` template from this file:

```
../woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php
```

You can override the `no-products-found.php` template by copying the template to your child theme: `YOURTHEME/woocommerce/loop/no-products-found.php`.

WooCommerce uses slightly different language than you posted, so it's possible your theme already has a custom `no-products-found.php` template.

Another options is to create/edit the Turkish PO file.  [WordPress.org has more details](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/internationalization/localization/). If you edit the plugin/theme files directly, your translations will be overwritten when they are updated.

Comment: I dont have a this path "YOURTHEME/woocommerce/loop/no-products-found.php."
But anyway i know where is no-products-found.php.
But they dont include my message "No More Available Items"

Comment: The theme or a plugiin could be overriding that template somewhere else.  First, try searching for the specific string in all theme/plugin code.  Then, try using Query Monitor plugin to see which hooks and functions are firing on that page.

Comment: I listened to your advice. I created a new PO file with the Loco Translate plugin. That's enough for now for the solution I want!